# Clarify on an identification space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider that a triangle, whose edges are named $a$, $b$ and $c$; identify $a$ and $b$ with the same orientation (although the orientation doesn't matter for my question). Now, it seems to me that we obtained the space $S^1\vee S^1 $: in fact the three vertices of the triangle are identified to one point, the sides $a$ and $b$ are glued to form one of the copies of $S^1$, and $c$ forms the other copy.

However the solutions say that, since there is an edge that is not identified with the others, the result space is $S^1$, and I don't understand where I am wrong. Actually, it seems to me that if we had three edges identified, then we would obtain $S^1$, because all of them would be glued to form only one copy of $S^1$. Can you clarify my ideas on this situation? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, then the resulting space is $S^1$ with a copy of the unit interval attached at a point. In particular, the three vertices are _not_ identified to a point: the two vertices to which $c$ is attached are, but the third vertex stays intact.

Comment: Or do you mean that the two edges are _identified to a point_? In that case, you really get $S^1$ because $a$ and $b$ do not form a copy of $S^1$ as you claim; they're collapsed to a point!

Comment: @BenSteffan your description in the first comment is the right one; however I don't understand why the vertex between $a$ and $b$ is not identified with the other two. Let's call $ab$ the vertex between the two edges $a$ and $b$, and in the same way call the other two $bc$ and $ac$. Since $a$ and $b$ are identified with the same orientation, we have that $ac$ is identified with $ab$, and also $ab$ and $bc$ are identified; so they are all identified to one point. This does not depend on how you drew the triangle, as long as $a$ and $b$ are the two edges that you choose to identify. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that this does depend on the direction of identification (not sure what you mean by "orientation doesn't matter"). If you identify points from $a$ and $b$ (counter)clockwise then you endup with 3 vertices identified. But if you identify points from $a$ clockwise with points of $b$ counterclockwise then only two vertices get identified and the third one (the common vertex of $a$ and $b$) is left alone. I think that the former construction yields $S^1\vee S^1$ as you said, while the latter yields $S^1\vee [0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you @freakish, you're right; I don't know why I said that this doen't depend on orientation. Anyway in my case we identify both of them clockwise, so you agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem reduces to the following: let $X=[0,2]$ and let $A=[0,1]$. Assume that $g:[0,1]\to [1,2]$ is a homeomorphism. We have a relationship $x\sim g(x)$ for $x\in A$. What is $X/\sim$?

It is easy to see that there's a continuous surjection $p:[0,1]\to X/\sim$ given by $p(t)=[t]_\sim$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact then this means that $p$ is a quotient map and thus $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]/\sim'$, where $\sim'$ is the restriction of $\sim$. It is easy to see that $[t]_{\sim'}=\{t\}$ for $t\in (0,1)$. The only question is what happens for $0,1$. There are two cases:

- $g(0)=1$, and $g(1)=2$, i.e. $g$ "preserves the direction". Thus $[0]_{\sim'}=\{0, 1\}$. In that case $[0,1]/\sim'$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$
- $g(0)=2$ and $g(1)=1$, i.e. $g$ "reverses the direction". Thus $[0]_{\sim'}=\{0\}$ and $[1]_{\sim'}=\{1\}$. And so $p$ is a homeomorphism.

Therefore, depending on the direction of the identification, the result is either $S^1$ or $[0,1]$.

Now by adding the third edge we only collapse its ends and so we glue additional $S^1$ into our result.

All in all, the answer is:

- $S^1\vee S^1$ when identifying in the same direction or
- $S^1\vee [0,1]$ otherwise